# Absolute construction with or without "with"

Tags: absolute-clauses, absolute-construction

> When the volunteers catch wind of dire financial situation, they rent a stall at the flea market. Neighbours empty their cupboards and garages, with the money raised paying our living expenses.

The sentences stated above have been taken from a story named ***Your son is in a coma*** published in **Reader's Digest**, January 2006. I cannot find the name of the author of this story.
Here ***with the money raised paying our living expenses*** is an absolute construction. What would happen if I omit ***with*** or don't use ***with*** and write it in the following way?

> ..., the money raised paying our living expenses.

Answer (score 1):

It is a participial clause which expresses a consequence. I would not object it.

Comment: Í would not object it? What does that mean?

Comment: @Lambie He meant to say "**object to it**".

Comment: @Lambie — Missed a word… they call it 'text-processing'. Ever heard about it?